# vba variations across office suite

Tags: vba

what kind of functionality variation is there across vba for excel vs vba for access vs vba for word, etc..

i know that probably 95% it's the same. but what is that 5% of differences consistent of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a VBA editor and go to the object browser (F2).  Click the dropdown that says `<All Libraries>`.  Here you can see all the libraries available by default in the current application.  Regardless of which application you're in, you'll always see the Office, VBA, and stdole libraries.  You'll also see a library with functions specific to the current application: Word, Excel, etc.

If you look at the application-specific libraries you'll see that they contain objects and methods specific to that application - cells, worksheets, and formulas in Excel; paragraphs, styles, and mail merges in Word; etc.